# Adding images directly to public folder

Tags: image, upload

I have over 9000 photos that I need to add to my site however using the upload feature in assets is taking an extremely long time. I have tried to just simply add the images to the correct folder in public but they are not showing up on craft. Is there something additional I must do for them to show up or is using the upload feature the only way for photos to show in assets?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [Update Asset Indexes](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets#updating-your-asset-indexes) tool in Settings in the control panel:

> Whenever there are files within your asset source that were not added directly by Craft (e.g. via FTP), you will need to tell Craft to go and look for them. You can do that from the “Update Asset Indexes” tool within Settings.

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't seem to do anything. The process finishes pretty quickly but would I have to wait a bit for anything to show up since there are 9000+ photos?

Comment: 9000 files would take a fairly long time to index. Are you sure you've added them to the correct folder? What kind of files are you adding – jpegs, pngs or something else?